# Java OpenCV cant copy from MatOfInt4 into MatOfInt4

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have an OpenCV 4.2.0 application using HoughLinesP to detect lines in an image that's working fine with C++ and Objective-C. Now I need to have the same functionality working for java on Android.

I've been fighting with it for a couple of days now and boiled it down to the following issue.  I can't copy a value from one MatOfInt4 to another MatOfInt4 using a for loop with `lines2.put(i,0, lines.get(i, 0));`

Below is the piece of code and the log outputs.  There are no compiler errors or runtime errors, just no values saved in the lines2 destination MatOfInt4. Either I have misunderstood how the put method works or there is something else wrong.

Does anyone know where this could be going wrong?  Any experts with Java and OpenCV able to give any guidance or corrections to the code below so that it will work?

You can see lines has 180 entries, the for loop counts 180 loops but lines2 is empty when it's finished.  I can `get()` the values correctly from lines and I'm using the values in other parts of the code, but I can't `put()` anything into lines2.

```
MatOfInt4 lines = new MatOfInt4();

lines = houghLinesP(sub);

Log.i(TAG, "Total Sub Lines Returned: " + lines.size());

MatOfInt4 lines2 = new MatOfInt4();

for(int i = 0; i <  lines.rows(); i++) {

    lines2.put(i,0, lines.get(i, 0));

    Log.i(TAG, "Count of loop: " + i);
}

Log.i(TAG, "Dump of lines2 Returned: " + lines2.dump());

Log.i(TAG, "Total Lines2 Returned: " + lines2.size());
```

Results of test code:

Total Sub Lines Returned: 1x180

Dump of lines2 Returned: []

Count of loop: 180

Total Lines2 Returned: 0x0

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lines2` matrix has no size, so you cannot set values in it. To solve the problem you can allocate the matrix with the appropriate size, e.g.

```java
MatOfInt4 lines2 = new MatOfInt4();
lines2.create(1,lines.rows(), lines.type());

// alternatively:
Mat lines2 = new Mat(1,lines.rows(), lines.type());
```

If you don't do anything else in the loop you could also just transpose the matrix to achieve the same result:

```java
Mat lines2 = lines.t();
```

This transposed matrix will already contain the correct values. For my example image this produces the following output:

```
Total Sub Lines Returned: 1x295
Dump of lines2 Returned: [9, 187, 137, 201, 353, 211, 430, 213, 95, etc...
Total Lines2 Returned: 295x1
```

Comment: Hi @Jannik, Thats awesome, thanks very much for the help and clear explanation.  As I am doing something in the loop I need to use one of your first options.